# Path in a Wordpress + Prestashop website

Tags: wordpress, path, styling, prestashop

I have a wordpress website with a Prestashop (/shop) installed in the wp root folder.
Linking between the 2 sites works fine.

But, after i moved my prestashop folder from my old website into the new wordpress site, a lot of my styling and images has been destroyed..

The Prestashop itself works fine, and also the images included from Prestashop backoffice are working.
For what i can see, my custom css for prestashop styling is gone and also my images in /img.

My question is, maybe i can turn this around and optimize my site, by adding the styling and images from my wp theme sheets and img folder - since the structure of the site, should be the same anyways..
- Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Prestashop few time ago in a folder of my website.

For my website I used Wordpress, too.

For me [Prestashop Forums](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/) was really good for guidance. You can ask there for help.